# Advantage of video memory for non-gaming use

Tags: memory, graphics-card, video-editing, integrated-graphics

So, I finally get a computer where I do not have to juggle the memory.  Going from 8 to 32 Gb, I actually have some to spare.  Setting up the new computer, I came across the video memory configuration, and that got me wondering: would it do me any good to increase it?

My question, then, is twofold: first, are there any sensible advantages of increasing video memory for non-gaming daily use?  In my case, that means office and communication tools, programming IDEs and tools, terminals and virtual machines running the same kind of programs as listed before.  And if so, how can I tell how much additional memory actually helps, how much would be a waste of memory?  I use a secondary monitor around 50% of the time, not sure if that affects the response

Second, I play a bit with Gimp and Blender now and then, mostly to edit (cut) videos.  Does the answer change, then?

If you can  point me to any references on how this work, I'd appreciate.  From what I could read so far, video memory use is kind of a black box.  My understanding from what I read is that it is mostly used to store images, buffered video and textures, and that it magically uses as much memory as is available, with the advantage coming from not re-reading them from disk?

Comment: If you are reserving system memory for the GPU, then your page file on your system disk has nothing to do with anything, your page file has nothing to do with VRAM (Video RAM)

Comment: Sorry, @Ramhound, I'm not following.  I had not mentioned page file, why are you bringing that up?

Comment: "not re-reading them from disk?" - I assumed you meant the page file. Video memory isn't a "black box" it's used to perform computations.  This can either be dedicated or shared (system memory).

Comment: My "black box" comment would be on how it is controlled or managed, as in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5695427/8280541).  The _not re-reading them from disk_ comment, again, is my guess